# Custom Metadata Relationships and Compound Fields

Tags: custom-metadata, metadata-relationship

Custom Metadata Types now support relationships, so we can have a reference to an object and even references to field definitions. Is there a way to reference the individual parts of compound fields, for instance FirstName and LastName on the Contact object? It doesn't appear to be possible, but wanted to see if anyone has found anything contradictory before I stick with plain old text fields instead.

[Custom Metadata Relationship Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_relationships_limits.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Metadata Types now support relationships to EntityParticles. So you can now reference compound fields in relationships. Take a look at the article for more info - [Create a Relationship to a Field Definition or Entity Particle](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_relationships_field_particle.htm&type=0)

In Winter '21 release, we are adding support for Geolocation compound field.

Answer (score 6):

We don't yet support this. FieldDefinition only includes fields as defined on the object, not individual subfields.

We are thinking about (but haven't yet ranked in our priority list) also allowing relationships to EntityParticle. EntityParticle would include any field or subfield on the object that is supported in a SOQL select clause.

Comment: Thanks for a catagorical answer, and please do add EntityParticle support! I believe the kind of code dealing with these relationships is the kind of code that'll need granular access to these fields.

Comment: This is bummer. @Avrom, any updates since your last comment?

Matt Lacey, besides replacing field relationship with text fields, are they are any other workarounds you have come across?

Comment: @SalesforceArchitect, here's what I have as of now: 1) This isn't scheduled for the Summer '18 release, but 2) It's high on the priority list and is (forward-looking statement) being at least seriously considered for Winter '19.

Comment: Happy holidays! Safe harbor of course, but any updates on the priority of `EntityParticle`?

Comment: I believe that it's below getting formula references to custom metadata records working in process builder, but above pretty much everything else.